# Cumulative number by group SQL in one select statement

Tags: sql, count, sequence, window-functions

This is what the data looks like:

| ID | Date | Person | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01012020 | API | NEW |
| 1 | 02012020 | REMCO | OKAY |
| 1 | 03012020 | API | RECALC |
| 1 | 04012020 | RUUD | OKAY |
| 1 | 05012020 | API | RECALC |
| 1 | 06012020 | MICHAEL | OKAY EXTRA INFO |
| 1 | 07012020 | ROY | OKAY |
| 1 | 08012020 | ROY | OKAY |

I have to add a row that shows the version of this ID. The version is adding up when after a person other than API is handling the ID.

The sequence should start with 1.

So the result should look like:

| ID | Date | Person | Status | VERSION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01012020 | API | NEW | 1 |
| 1 | 02012020 | REMCO | OKAY | 1 |
| 1 | 03012020 | API | RECALC | 2 |
| 1 | 04012020 | RUUD | OKAY | 2 |
| 1 | 05012020 | API | RECALC | 3 |
| 1 | 06012020 | MICHAEL | OKAY EXTRA INFO | 3 |
| 1 | 07012020 | ROY | OKAY | 4 |
| 1 | 08012020 | ROY | OKAY | 5 |

Sure you can use CTE or INNER JOIN. **But I need this result to be in the SELECT statement**. I have tried this:

```sql
SUM(    case    when STATUS IN ( 'NEW', 'RECALC') THEN 0
                else 1 end)
over( partition by ID order by Date asc)

as VERSION
```

This almost does it, but stops adding version numbers when a person is handeling the version. Which it should not do.

please ask if this isnt clear!

```
SUM(    case    when STATUS IN ( 'NEW', 'RECALC') THEN 0
                else 1 end)
over( partition by ID order by Date asc)

as VERSION
```

This stopped adding versions when a person keeps handeling the version. It should keep adding up versions.

It basically needs to add a version number when a person is done with it. So the row after a person reviewd the ID should add 1. API is not a person, everyone else is :)

Comment: That didnt work. It stopped adding up on the last three records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The version is adding up when **after** a person other than API is handling the ID.

This reads like count of "non-API" rows over all *preceding* rows (not including the current rows.

You did not tag your database. A reasonably portable approach is to express the count with a conditional `sum`, and to use the `rows between` syntax to adjust the window frame:

```
select  t.*,
    1 + coalesce(
        sum(case when person != 'API' then 1 else 0 end) over(
            partition by id
            order by date
            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
        ),
        0
      ) as grp
from mytable t
order by id, date
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/t3AAS2zj):

| id | date | person | status | grp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | API | NEW | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 | REMCO | OKAY | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-01-03 | API | RECALC | 2 |
| 1 | 2020-01-04 | RUUD | OKAY | 2 |
| 1 | 2020-01-05 | API | RECALC | 3 |
| 1 | 2020-01-06 | MICHAEL | OKAY EXTRA INFO | 3 |
| 1 | 2020-01-07 | ROY | OKAY | 4 |
| 1 | 2020-01-08 | ROY | OKAY | 5 |

Comment: You just saved my day! Can you explain, if you have time, how that works?  Especially the rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding

Comment: @JoostOskam: `rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding` means : consider all preceding rows (as defined by the `order by date` clause), but not the current row.